# Getting file content 'php://input' not working

Tags: php, json, rest, file-get-contents

I have PHP application try to get post JSON in 'php://input' using 'file_get_contents' function. Only empty string return. Below is the full code line.

```
$_PUT = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
```

Or i need to change any apache/php settings?

Comment: How are you constructing the request?

Comment: From the Doc: "php://input is not available with enctype="multipart/form-data"."

Comment: Request are using Angular $resource and data in JSON format. So @TobiasSpringer , i need to modified the header while sending the post? im using this header `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`

Comment: If you're PUTing JSON, you should use `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`. Make sure you track the request, for example in google chrome network tab, to ensure you are actually sending a request body

Answer (score 1):

> im using this header `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`

If your data is application/x-www-form-urlencoded, then you should access it via `$_POST` and not touch the raw HTTP request body. You only do that if you are using an atypical content-type (such as `application/json`).

If your data isn't in that format, then you should use the correct Content-Type header.

Comment: Still battling, the proposed solution not working. Checked the header thoroughly and it sending using the exactly as per code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear cache of php and server. Then try another solution:

```
$_PUT = json_decode(stream_get_contents(STDIN));
```

I hope it will fix.